# How to stop 'Send order notification' & 'Send payment notification' in checkout process from code side in kentico

Tags: kentico

I know there is option in kentico admin setting to stop the sending notification email. but I want to check this in the code for my customization. so could you please suggest me where should I get the code in kentico.

[Setting in kentico](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8CJm.png)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the official [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/api10/configuration/settings).

You need to use `SettingsKeyInfoProvider`:

```c#
SettingsKeyInfoProvider.SetValue("CMSSettingName", "SiteName", value);
```

Leave out the site name parameter if you want to set it globally.

The settings names you are looking for are `CMSStoreSendOrderNotification` and `CMSStoreSendPaymentNotification`.

You can find more settings by querying the DB:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [CMS_SettingsKey] where keyname like '%cmsstoresend%'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to intercept an action when a notification is being sent, you can use Global events for the `EmailInfo` object like this:

```
[assembly: RegisterModule(typeof(GlobalEventsModule))]
public class GlobalEventsModule : Module
{
    public GlobalEventsModule() : base (typeof(GlobalEventsModule).Name)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnInit()
    {
        base.OnInit();

        EmailInfo.TYPEINFO.Events.Insert.Before += Insert_Before;
    }

    private void Insert_Before(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
    {
         // executed before an e-mail is inserted into DB
         var email = (EmailInfo)e.Object;
    }
}
```

To cancel the execution in code you can call `Cancel()` method (although you might get exceptions in this case - you have to test for yourself in your scenario):

```
private void Insert_Before(object sender, ObjectEventArgs e)
{
    var email = (EmailInfo)e.Object;

    e.Cancel();
}
```

This will also work only if you are using Email queue (which is **highly recommended** anyway) and will be executed for **all** outgoing e-mails, not just notifications.

Answer (score 1):

Using the CMS.Ecommerce library you can check these settings through the API

`SiteInfoIdentifier sii = new SiteInfoIdentifier(SiteContext.CurrentSiteID);
    bool sendOrderNotificationEmail = CMS.Ecommerce.ECommerceSettings.SendOrderNotification(sii);`

If you wanted to set them programmatically you would have to use the SettingsKeyInfoProvider
    `SettingsKeyInfoProvider.SetValue("CMSStoreSendOrderNotification ", false);`